# Calling a parent controller's function in the parent's context

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I need my parent controller function **getDataInParent** to get called in the parent's controller's context itself.

Sample:

The child directive is correctly setup like this from within the parent directive template:

```
<child get-data="parentCtrl.getDataInParent"></child>
```

And here is a simple mockup of my controller implementations (see comments in getDataInParent):

```
// *** parent controller
controller('parentController', [...., function(){

var that = this;
that.someData = ...;

that.getDataInParent = function(someArgs){
    // Here I need to access "that.someData" and other 
    // properties/methods of this parent controller. But I can't!
    // Because this method doesn't seemed to be called in the context of this controller.
};
};]

// *** child controller
controller('childController', [...., function(){

var that = this;

// Hooked up correctly and am able to call the parent's function like this:
var dataFromParent = $scope.getData().(someArgs);
};]
```

This seems like a very common scenario that a lot of people would have encountered, so I am hoping there should be a straight forward solution for this in Angular.

Comment: Show us the directive declaration. Common approach is to pass the function into isolated scope. Can also use `bindToController` in newer versions of angular.  Create a demo that reproduces problem. Should always provide a [mcve]

Comment: Charlie, I will try to create an online sample. What would be the best place? Plunker?

Comment: Plunker is very easy yes

Comment: Charlie, I figured the problem with the sample below, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always create a local scope for a directive & bind the parent function to the local scope using this '**&**'. Suppose this is your html

```
<child get-data="parentCtrl.getDataInParent(params)"></child>
```

This should be your directive code.

```
angular
    .module('SampleApp')
    .directive('child', child);

/* @ngInject */
function child() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'templateUrl',
        scope: {
          getData : '&'
        },
        link: linkFunc,
        controller: 'Controller',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    };

    return directive;

    function linkFunc(scope, el, attr, ctrl) {
      // Calling parent method here
      var dataFromParent = $scope.getData({params: "SomeParams"});
    }
}
```

Working Plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/4n61WF4JN3eT2QcdnnTw?p=preview

Comment: Sasank this is exactly how I have setup already. And the issue I mention in the original post persists. If you have something like this in any of your projects, would be very easy to see the same issue there too.

Comment: Here it is executing , check https://plnkr.co/edit/4n61WF4JN3eT2QcdnnTw?p=preview

Comment: Yes, it does seem to work! Thanks. Let me check what is different about my code.

Comment: Found the problem, I had incorrectly set up the HTML directive. See yours and mine to see the difference. It works now! Many thanks.